# Displaying label if field contains 'X' or 'Y' value in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, fields-attributes, expression, visualisation

Trying to create an expression to display labels from a field called `"Drilled ID"`, but only if the field named `"Status"` contains *'Week'* or *'Active'* but to no avail. If the `"Status"` field contains anything other than these two options, then it can be left blank.

I have tried this:

```
case
  when "Drilled ID" = 'Week' or 'Active'
    then "Drilled ID"
end
```

I can get it to work by creating two different rules on rule-based labelling, but I was wondering if there is another way?

Comment: Try this: `when "Drilled ID" = 'Week' or   "Drilled ID" = 'Active'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found another solution.

```
Case
When "Status" like 'Active' or "Status" like 'Week' 
Then "Drilled ID"
End
```

Answer (score 10):

Use this:

```
CASE
  WHEN "Status" IN ('Week', 'Active')
    THEN "Drilled ID"
END
```